# Skipping pages in xamarin forms in Back Navigation

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, navigation

Four page xamarin forms, pages 1>2>3>4 with page 4 as the last page to navigate to

After Navigating to page 4, i want to go back to page 2, skipping page 3

I tried putting a button on page 4 that navigates back to page 2

But after clicking the Back button, it brings me back to page 4 instead of page 1

im stuck

Comment: this is covered in the docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical#manipulating-the-navigation-stack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that you have 4 pages in your navigation stack *1>2>3>4* and now you want to go from Page 4 to Page 2. You have to **remove** Page 3, You **can not** navigate to Page 2 Because then the stack will become this ***`1>2>3>4>2`***. You want the stack to be like **`1>2>4`** .So when you pop from Page 4 it goes to Page 2.

Code to remove Page 3 from stack

```
var page = Navigation.NavigationStack[Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 2]; 
// you have the second last page now in page variable
Navigation.RemovePage(page);
```

after this stack will become **`1>2>4`**
Now, you can write following in page 4

```
await Navigation.PopAsync();
```

And you'll come to page 2.

Comment: thank you, this is the most clear answer i've had so far, really thanks